# What do I need to do to tweak my Drupal Apache (Localhost) on Ubuntu to run faster

Tags: apache, ubuntu, drupal

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (from 13.10) at home on a desktop and for the best part of 12 months my localhost for Drupal 7.27 runs at a 'snails pace' for simple working read/write updates and is unbelievable slow to work with!

What do I need to do to make it work more effectively as a home workstation (desktop or laptop)?

Any advice for a newbie is most welcome to get the best out of open source LAMP webdevsl.

Failing that I'll simply ditch 3 projects worth of 12 months effort and start afresh as a beginner with Django, surely that can't be that slow LOL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible this may have done the trick: realpath_cache_size = 16M see https://drupal.org/node/961012 My realpath_cache_size was set to 16k. Please comment on any other ideas for speed up of home based computer using ubuntu 14.04 LAMP for Drupal 7.xx webdev

Comment: Hi readers, don't know if this helps, but since my original post above and then having updated to Ubuntu 15.04 I still had no success in increasing the speed, until today (Oct' 15) when I took a 'stab' at installing the MySQL Workbench 6.1. (from Ubuntu software centre install) and what a difference! Now all my Drupal v7.3x sites pages load in an average 1.5-2 seconds as opposed to some 45+ seconds. None of the original answers really made a difference, but if you are reading this, running Ubuntu desktop for localhost Drupal webdev, then give the Workbench install a try, good luck.

Comment: I would personally be interested to know, just what the MySQL Workbench 6.1 install has done to make a difference! (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to speed up Drupal on localhost, and here are some suggestions:

- **Use [Memcache](http://memcached.org/)**

  > Memcache is a system that works to speed up virtual private servers
  >   by caching server information. The program allows you to allocate a
  >   specific amount of the server ram toward caching recently queried data
  >   for a certain amount of time. Once the data is requested again,
  >   memcache speeds up the process of retrieving it by displaying the
  >   cached information instead of generating the result from the database.

  After installing and configuring Memcache, download and enable Drupal [Memcache API](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) module
- **Use [APC](http://us.php.net/apc)**

  > The Alternative PHP Cache (APC) is a free and open opcode cache for
  >   PHP. Its goal is to provide a free, open, and robust framework for
  >   caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code.

  After installing and configuring APC, download and enable Drupal [APC](https://drupal.org/project/apc) module
- **Use [Varnish cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)**

  > Varnish is a web application accelerator. You install it in front of your web application and it will speed it up significantly.

  After installing and configuring Varnish, download and enable Drupal [Varnish HTTP Accelerator Integration](https://drupal.org/project/varnish) module
- **Use Drupal [Cache Expiration](https://drupal.org/project/expire) module**

  > This module provides configurable actions upon events that will expire
  >   URLs from caches like reverse proxy caches, internal page caches,
  >   etc.This module make more sense when Minimum Cache Lifetime setting is
  >   set to a value other than none.

Also, I recommend you to use [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition) instead of default Ubuntu PHP stack.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time to reply and giving me some excellent pointers and advice on speeding up Drupal 7.xx on (in my case Ubuntu 14.04 O/S). I'm going to mark this answer as 'accepted' because it give me various options in one reply. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it is lampp stack then you can try editing **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**
from

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1`

to

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

if the above line is not there then you can add it.

This is got from 
[How to improve Druopal Localhost](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/how-to-improve-drupal-speed-when-developing-in-localhost)